# jquery Scroll event in $(window), find out the position difference

Tags: jquery

I'm using:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
.....
});
```

How can i find out the number of pixels (and the direction, if absolute number) that were scrolled?

Thanx

Comment: beware of using the scroll event http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: thanks, i'll definitely keep that in mind

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to determine what you're looking for.

Comment: i'm not the one doing the scroll. I'm grabbing the event when the scroll occurs by the user. I want to know how much has it scrolled

Comment: scrollTop will return a pixel value if you're not passing it one for how far the page has scrolled from the top of the document. Maybe give some more example code for what you want to figure out.

Comment: i'm sorry them i will try it out. i thought scrollTop was just a void function

Answer (score 13):

Here is one way:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var lastScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        var newScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
        console.log(newScroll - lastScroll);
        lastScroll = newScroll;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a little more useful than my answer as you're getting the scrolled value for any given scroll, not just from the time the document loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The line below doesn't work on Firefox 19 (which I updated this year: 2013).

```
var lastScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
```

The solution, which will also improve the cross browser compatibility, is to use a jQuery call:

```
var lastScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
```

Final result:

```
$(function(){
    var lastScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        var newScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        console.log(newScroll - lastScroll);
        lastScroll = newScroll;
    });
});
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using this:

```
$('selector').bind('scroll', function(e){
    e.currentTarget.scrollTop; // .scrollLeft ...
});
```