# Bootstrap 3 - Have sticky Accordion header on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with Bootstrap 3, and would like to be able to have the accordion header text replace some text in the navigation bar:

```
<nav>
  <div id="current"></div>
</nav>
```

I would like this action to work as follows:

- When accordion section hits the top of the page (user scrolling down), change the text content of `<div id"current"></div>` with the text content of the accordion's `h1`.
- When page is at the top, set `<div id"current"></div>` to blank

What javascript/jQuery/Bootstrap3 JS code should I use to make this happen ?

Example Bootstrap 3 `collapse` (Accordion)

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The segments above in `<h4 class="panel-title"><a .... > Foo </a</h4>` is what I am looking to capture when that moves up or down on the screen from the visible portion of the page to the prior secgment.  So if `Foo` is above the page, but you are still in that accordion panels contents, then `Foo` will be displayed in the `<div>` tag I first mentioned. In the event that `Foo` is (lets say 1/2 down the page), and part of `Bar` (a different segment) is partially visible, then `Bar` would show in the first mentioned `<div>`.  Lastly, in the event that the user is at the top of the page, then the `<div>` first mentioned will not show anything.

I hope this helps to clarify.  I have seen some examples of this type of functionality on various sites, however I have never really inspected the code as it was not something I was doing at the time -- was more just a cool feature on the site.  The specific site(s) that have this functionality are buried somewhere deep within Google's dark corners now.

Comment: What is an *accordian*?

Comment: @n.1 - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: *Accordian* is rarely used contrary to *accordion*, I find it disturbing to use the less common spelling.

Comment: @n.1 - typo corrected.  Are you able to give any insight into the issue.  The question is still valid regardless of the spelling err.

Comment: Please show some code, what have you tried?

Comment: @DanFromGermany - I do not have any code as I do not know where to begin to approach this code problem. Showing the source of an accordion written in BS3 would be counterproductive as the accordion layout is clearly defined in the BS3 documentation. -- However, I will paste and explain a bit more using the BS3 `collapse` accordion example source from the link provided above.

Comment: 1. Keyword [`scrollspy`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399021/jquery-scroll-event-in-window-find-out-the-position-difference) 2. attach event handlers according to the scroll position 3. change the contents of the elements using `$('current').text($('#your-h1').text());`

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Will look into it.  Setting the value obviously isn't the issue here -- it's more the event when that element reaches or passes the top of the page (-70px due to BS3 Nav bar)

Comment: @DanFromGermany - ScrollSpy is a bit different than what I am looking for.  I am not checking if the user has scrolled -- that is pretty easy -- I am looking for the specific element that the user is scrolling through currently.  Give me a minute and I will try and dig up an example site --- (god i wish I bookmarked them last year when I saw this).  ScrollTo X position is something way out in left field from this.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Seems I got lucky ---  take a look at this >> http://polarblau.github.io/stickySectionHeaders/  .. It is close to what I want to do, but instead of making the header sticky, I want to to scroll normally, but trigger an event that updates the `<div>`, using BS3 .  I hope this is more helpful in clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention that the scroll detection is easy, the final challenge appears to be detecting which accordion is currently selected.

By going to the example by [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples) and inspecting the elements while collapsing and expanding them.

When expanded, the expanded content has the following classes

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="height: auto;">
```

And when collapsed:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: auto;">
```

So we can find the currently active div by searching for the div with all three classes `panel-collapse collapse in`, check which ID it has (in this case `collapseOne`) and in code keep a list of titles corresponding to these lines and assign them to your header once the scroll event is triggered.

The JS for getting the open accordion would go like this (with JQuery as you already use it)

```
var titles = {
    collapseOne: "title for section 1",
    collapseTwo: "title for section 2",
};
function getCurrentTitle(){
    var selectedID = $(".panel-collapse.collapse.in")[0].id;
    $("#current").html(titles[selectedID]);
}
```